# Fedora installed on Windows Partition

Tags: fedora, windows, dual-boot, hard-disk, resize2fs

I have installed Fedora 32 on  a 1 TB drive, which was filled up with data. I have resized to 50 GB, because there was no bigger value to choose and I had 50 GB free to use. After I installed it on the drive, I couldn't get any access from my Windows 7 install, which is running on another drive. How can I get access to my data? I think it is not deleted because when I'm on Fedora it shows only 50 GB of free space, and in the Windows installer per DVD, it shows that 940 GB are used.

---

**Edit**: As requested:

```
# lsblk
NAME                            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                               8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 
├─sda1                            8:1    0   100M  0 part 
└─sda2                            8:2    0 465,7G  0 part 
sdb                               8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1                            8:17   0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sdb2                            8:18   0 930,5G  0 part 
  ├─fedora_localhost--live-root 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─fedora_localhost--live-swap 253:1    0   7,9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─fedora_localhost--live-home 253:2    0 872,6G  0 lvm  /home
sr0                              11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: During installation, did you get warning that you were installing on a disk or partition that was in use?

Comment: no, on  the partition was only data. No system Partition.

Comment: Provide the output of `lsblk` from Fedora.

Comment: It doesn't matter if there was only "data".  Did you install Fedora in an existing partition or into a partition created in free space on that disk.  In the first case I'd expect Fedora to give you a warning.  What did you resize to 50Gb?

Comment: i created it on a exsiting partition. Can i undo that anyway?

Comment: No, you will need your backups to recover your data.  Is there a reason you do not answer the questions we ask?  Language?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, your 1 TB disk has been completely re-partitioned by the Fedora installer and any partitions that were there before have been deleted.

It now contains two partitions: the first partition is 1 GB in size and contains the /boot filesystem of Fedora, and the second partition covers all the rest and is used by Linux LVM.

As far as Windows is concerned, both of these are wholly incomprehensible: the first partition uses a filesystem type Windows has no drivers for, and the second partition is using another system to further sub-divide it, a system Windows has no clue about.

IF you use the `df -h` command, you should see that you have multiple filesystems: `/boot` is about 1 GB in size (or slightly less because of filesystem overhead), `/`, your root filesystem, is 50 GB in size, and `/home` filesystem that occupies most of the remaining space (872.6 GB according to the `lsblk` output).

However, since you are not using encryption, most of the disk space has not been overwritten yet: with appropriate data recovery software, you might be able to restore at least some files from the not-yet-overwritten part. If you want to try this, you should **immediately stop using this disk**: any new files written to the Linux filesystems may overwrite parts of what is left of your original Windows files, making the problem worse.

For the recovery, you will need another disk to store the recovered files (**don't repartition the problem disk or write to it any more** until you're sure you've recovered all you can), and a program that can scan the full contents of the disk and recover any files it can find that way, even when the partition table and the original Windows filesystem metadata is no longer available. [TestDisk and/or PhotoRec from CGSecurity](https://www.cgsecurity.org/) are free recovery programs that might be worth a try.

If the data that was on the disk had significant value, you might want to contact some data recovery professionals instead.